# AltBeacon - Detect RadiusNetwork USB Beacon - How to get correct BeaconLayout

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am trying to use AltBeacon to detect RadiusNetwork beacons. I am aware that i need to use setBeaconLayout() to get beacons(other than AltBeacons) detected. But, I am not sure how to get the Layout for the beacons that i want to use. I am pretty new to beacons.

Right now i have RadiusNetwork beacon, with ID "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6" (for example), how do i get the Layout for this? I tried googling, but didn't get much help. Is there a way to get the layout pattern for devices? If at a later stage, i want to use some other device, how do i find the layout for that device?

Will this work?

```
mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region("RadBeacon USB",
                Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"),
                Identifier.parse("1"), Identifier.parse("1"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the following code below for RadBeacon. I am still not sure on how to get the correct BeaconLayout for a beacon, but the following worked for me.

```
    mBeaconManager
            .getBeaconParsers()
            .add(new BeaconParser()
                    .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));

    mAllBeaconsRegion = new Region("RadBeacon",
            Identifier.parse("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"),
            Identifier.parse("1"), Identifier.parse("1"));
```